# Need clarification on Australia's Temporary Skill Shortage Visa (subclass 482)

Tags: australia

I want to check whether I am eligible for this visa or not.
First of all, I am 28.5 years old, I hold an Associate's degree in my relevant field (Computer Programming) and I have +6 years of relevant work experience. I can get IELTS 6 in all bands.

My general status looks fine for the visa, but to be assured to step forward, I need to know the answer to these questions:

1. Does my wife need to pass any IELTS exam?
2. Should I find the job myself? Or is there an online service or such thing by immigration department where I can find the employers who would nominate a worker of their need? Is it feasible to find a job **inside** Australia from **outside**? If yes, then how?

Comment: Ooh, I see, then I will ask my question there, thanks. Are there any pre-paid costs recruitment agencies charge you or they charge you after the contract?

Comment: In my experience, legit recruitment firms don't charge candidates any fees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TSS/subclass 482 visa, like the 457 visa it replaces, requires a **sponsoring employer**, full stop.  Your application will be rejected unless you have an Australian company that has given you a job offer and is willing to sponsor your visa, and you will have to find this sponsoring company yourself.  Australian job ads usually indicate whether they are open to sponsor visas, but the current government has made it much harder than it used to be only a few years ago.

On the upside, there are no language requirements for your dependents.